# interrupted to go to localhost:3000 that running by meteor

Tags: ubuntu, meteor, meteorite

I used firefox to go to my web that created by meteor 
but I cannot reach local host:3000 that running by meteor
while mrt shows "App running at: http;//localhost:3000/"

firefox shows:
The connection was interrupted
The connection to localhost:3000 was interrupted while the page was loading.
    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

but I can't find where and how to change firewall. 
thank for your reading

Comment: ok I changed to chrome, it finally works

Comment: ok thanks for letting us know. Please go ahead and delete your question then, since you are no longer expecting an answer.